# how to send parcelable class in android

Tags: android, bundle, parcelable

I have gone through a lot of solutions on SO. But none of them work for me. I am simply trying to send a parcelable class from one Activity to another using

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("parcelableMovie", (Parcelable) movieItemArrayList.get(position));
Intent intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, MovieDetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

I added a debugger point in **MovieDetailActivity.onCreate** and extras doesn't have anything. I tried changing my code in several ways. Like Casting `MovieItem` instead of `Parcelable`

**MovieDetailActivity.class**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if (extras != null) {
    //movieItem = (MovieItem) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("name_of_extra");

    movieItem = (MovieItem) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("parcelableMovie");

    //movieItem = (MovieItem) extras.getParcelable("parcelableMovie");
    if (movieItem != null) {
        movieTitle.setText(movieItem.getName());
        releasingDate.setText(movieItem.getReleaseDate());
    }
}
```

but movieItem always showing null

**Edit**
**MovieItem.java**

```
public class MovieItem implements Parcelable  {

    private String name;
    private String rating;
    private String releaseDate;
    private int image;

    public MovieItem(String name, String rating, String releaseDate, int image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.name);
        dest.writeString(this.rating);
        dest.writeString(this.releaseDate);
        dest.writeInt(this.image);
    }

    protected MovieItem(Parcel in) {
        this.name = in.readString();
        this.rating = in.readString();
        this.releaseDate = in.readString();
        this.image = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<MovieItem> CREATOR = new Creator<MovieItem>() {
        @Override
        public MovieItem createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new MovieItem(source);
        }

        @Override
        public MovieItem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MovieItem[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Does the object returned from `movieItemArrayList.get(position)` (MovieItem) implement the Parcelable interface?

Comment: You don't need a bundle, not that it is a solution to your problem, just a heads up. You can add the parcelable to the Intent without using a bundle wrapper by using putExtra(key, parcelable);

Comment: Please post `MovieItem` class. The class should be `Parcelable`.

Comment: I have included MovieItem class.

Comment: I think it is because you have used the method `getName()`. This is already a defined method in android. Try to convert it into `getMovieName()`.